# How do I represent a cube as an object that has different side colors?

Tags: java

So I'm working on a project where I have to make a cube object, but I'm having trouble trying to but it in code.

so far I have 2 classes, 1 for the cube and 1 for the sides. My issue is how do I create a cube object that takes in the colors for the sides?  Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

//So this would be my cube class where I would make an array of size 6 to represent each side of the cube my issue is how do I place each cube side element into the array?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Cube{


   Side[] cubeSides = new Side[6];

   Side top;
   Side left; 
   Side right;
   Side front;
   Side back;
   Side bottom;

   int id;


   public Cube(Side newTop, Side newLeft, Side newRight, Side newFront, Side newBack,     Side newBottom){

      top = newTop;
      left = newLeft;
      right = newRight;
      front = newFront;
      back = newBack;
      bottom = newBottom;

   }//Constructor



}//class


//this is my side class that just takes in a color for the side
import java.util.*;

public class Side{

   String color;

   public Side(String sideColor){

     color = sideColor;

  }//constructor

   String getColor(){

     return color;

  }//getColor
```

}//side

Comment: Things to consider and clarify on - 1) Does your cube need to handle rotation (i.e., if the "top" is blue and it's rotated 180 degrees on X, now the "bottom" is blue) 2) Does your cube need to serialize to a known format for representation?

Comment: "How do I place each cube side element into the array" is an extremely basic question. You may wish to go over the official [tutorial on arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) before continuing. You have the array declared, you have the 6 items, that tutorial will give you the info you need to figure out how to store those 6 items in that array.

Comment: Yes, the reason I chose array is because if i need to rotate it, I can just change the index of the color.

Answer (score 0):

For color representation, I think Enum is more suitable for your need. Such as

```
public enum Color {
  RED, BLUE, PINK, ORANGE, GREEN
}
```

and on top of that I think it's pointless to use array, as sides shall not be ordered. Cube.top looks fine to me. If you really need one variable to access all colors, you can use a HashMap instead, accessing it will be something like Cube.SideColors.get("Top")

Comment: So sorry, but I am not familiar with what Enum is, I need the sides to be ordered so that I can access each index. The thing is, I'm working on a game where I have to make 4 cube objects where each side of the cube is compared to each other when they are placed in a stack.

Comment: That's where you need some googling and self learning, I edited my answer with a brief example

Comment: @user2230712 `enum` allows you to define a set of constants in a type - see [Enum Types, The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: Actually, for `Color` representation, a [`java.awt.Color`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) would be the most appropriate, given that it is for storing colors, and it implements all necessary functionality and is generally compatible with built-in GUI code. No sense reinventing wheels.